# Should we put a limit on [limit]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[limit](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/limit) is a meta-tag used for a bunch of totally different purposes. Scanning the first page of questions I find questions about limiting

- screen resolution
- number of files
- downloaded amount
- parallel execution
- password size
- and much more (pretty much every question regards different limits)

That tag has *absolutely no relevance* for finding questions, also visible by only a single person monitoring it.

Comment: We must limit its exposure to a limited schema of limited nothingness!

Comment: Even limit must have limits ;)

Comment: limit has been limited